# How to hide header of createStackNavigator on React Native?

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

I want to hide header because I already have styled Toolbar in code:

```
import {createStackNavigator}
from 'react-navigation'
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator ({
  Home: HomePage,
  Friend: AddFriend,
  Bill: AddBill,
})
class App extends Component {
render() {
  return (
  <AppStackNavigator initialRouteName='Home'/>`<br>
  );
  }
}
export default App;
```

What should I add to my code?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

update your code like this code

```js
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator ({
    Home: {
        screen: HomePage, 
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null,
        },
    },
})
```

and if you dont want the header for all screens, then

```js
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator ({
    Home: {
        screen: HomePage,
    },
},
{
    navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
    },
})
```

Note: This solution is for an old version of React Navigation.

Comment: @JustAhead Awesome...if it helped, upvote and accept the answer..thanks!

Comment: @JustAhead any issues with my answer?

Comment: No, works perfect, when I am trying to vote for your answer, it says me  "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"

Comment: you should gain 15 points or more to upvote..but you can accept the answer i guess

Comment: Deprecation in 'navigationOptions':
- 'header: null' will be removed in a future version. Use 'headerShown: false' instead

Answer (score 34):

To disable headers for all views in a `createStackNavigator`, you can use `headerMode` option.

```js
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomePage,
  Friend: AddFriend,
  Bill: AddBill,
},
{
  headerMode: 'none',
})
```

Reference: [StackNavigatorConfig - createStackNavigator - React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#stacknavigatorconfig)

Comment: Thanks, this is the only answer that worked for me in react-navigation 3.5.1

Comment: Same as @Dror Bar, this is the only solution which worked for me using react-navigation@3.5.1

Comment: When I use two, nested one in the other, createStackNavigators, this works whilte `navigationOptions` didn't.

Answer (score 4):

Can you try:

```
static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
}
```

Inside your screen component.

Answer (score 2):

For hiding headers for specific screens or globally, you can do

```
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: HomePage,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null // Will hide header for HomePage
        }
    }
}, {
    navigationOptions: {
        header: null // Will hide header for all screens of current stack navigator,
        headerLeft: <HeaderLeft /> // Component to be displayed in left side of header (Generally it can be Hamburger)
        headerRight: <HeaderRight /> // Component to be displayed in right side of header
    }
})
```

Also note that, screen specific settings will override global settings.
Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 2):

try this
`options ={{ header: () => {}}}`
since you are explicitly not providing any argument to header function, it won't show any header.
For more information refer this: [react native docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation/)

Answer (score 1):

I used following code to hide the header.

```
   {
    navigationOptions: {
        header: null // Will hide header for all screens of current stack 

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

2020 UPDATE - REACT NAVIGATION 5+

Using `header : null` will not work anymore. In the options you need to set both ***headerMode*** to ***none*** along with ***headerShown*** to ***false*** as below:

```
<AuthStack.Navigator>
   <AuthStack.Screen name="AUTH" component={AuthScreen} options={{headerMode: 'none', headerShown : false}}/>
</AuthStack.Navigator>
```

Comment: `headerMode: 'none'` is not needed, just `headerShown : false` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers I could find were from React navigation v4 for some reason, which doesn't work in v5. After spending some time on it I figured out a way to hide toolbar in v5. Here it is:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

...

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

....
//and inside render
render(){
    return (
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen
                name="Home"
                component={HomeScreen}
                options={{
                  title: "Home",
                  headerShown: false,
                }}
              />
}
```

`headerShown: false,` this will do the trick

If you need help with migrating from v4 to v5 ->
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/

Answer (score 0):

```js
navigationOptions: { 
    header: null
}
```

is **deprecated**. The new is

```js
navigationOptions: { 
    headerShown: false
}
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62732551/8724367

Answer (score 0):

**React Navigation 6** (from October'21)

The solution below is not working anymore:

```
navigationOptions: {
  header: null,
},
```

Instead of `navigationOptions`, you want to use just `options`, and with `headerShown` set to `true`, which replaces the `header` set to `null`. The working solution:

```
options={{
  headerShown: true,
}}
```