# Deprecation in "navigationOptions": -"header: null" will be removed

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

React navigation version 4.3.9

My iOS emulator is throwing an annoying warning, but otherwise it works.

I have a stack navigator with a number of screens. My App.js file loads the stack navigator with the first screen showing. It's a console screen with a number of buttons that load screens from the stack navigator.

I want the first console screen not to have a header, as it doesn't fit with the designers layout.

This works fine:

```
  const PlanCalcNavigator = createStackNavigator({
   Console: {
     screen: ConsoleScreen,
     navigationOptions: {
       header: null // hides header in first screen
     }
   },
   PlanEvent: PlanEventScreen,
   Calc: CalculatorScreen,
  },
 );
```

But my iOS emulator keeps throwing up the "Deprecation in "navigationOptions": -"header: null" will be removed" warning which is very annoying.

Is there some other term that I can use that won't throw the error?

headerMode: 'none' doesn't work. It doesn't throw an error, but the console screen shows the header.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use

```
  navigationOptions:{
    headerShown: false
  }
```

Comment: in your stacknavigator
example:
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home:{
    screen:Home,
    navigationOptions:{
      title:"Feed",
      headerShown:false
    }....
  },

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
  <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

navigationOptions: {
header: null // hides header in first screen
}
That's good.
Need to upgrade React navigation version 4.4.0
You need to add headerMode as your fav.

Comment: I will probably go to version 5 for the next project, or once this is done and I have to do the inevitable upgrade to react-native.

Comment: If you fixed that problem, that's okay. I also had a problem same like you, I solved this problem by adding headerMode and upgrading react-navigation final version(4.4.0)